# Swiftui commands don't show Alert for MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, command

As in the following code, the alert don't work. Any work around or solution? Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct MessageCommands : Commands {

    @State private var send = false
    
    var body: some Commands {
            CommandMenu("Message") {
                    Button("Send", action: {
                        print("send message")
                        send = true
                    })
                            .alert(isPresented: $send) {
                                Alert(title: Text("file saved successfuly!"))
                            }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work?

Comment: The alert window doesn't show at all.

Comment: Maybe you can't show an alert from within a `CommandMenu` like this -- may need to attach it to somewhere else in the view hierarchy.